# Cannot convert existing ASP.NET MVC 2 solution to Azure Web Role in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I've been working on an ASP.NET MVC 2 (.NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2010) application for a while and have decided that I would like to deploy it as an Azure application.

After installing the latest (June 2010) Azure tools (through Visual Studio itself) I've added a blank `CloudService` to my solution. Whenever I try to add a "`Web Role Project in Solution`", however, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred trying to load the project properties window. 
Close the window and try again.
Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". 
The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path 
"obj\Debug|Any CPU\Cloud.dll". Illegal characters in path.  
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
```

I get this same error whenever I try to `Save All` or view the properties page for the `CloudService` project.

I imagine it's having trouble with the `Debug|Any CPU` part of the path, but can I remove it or word around it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what do you know. When had already sort of given up on this, seeing as how I could run en deploy the application anyway I decided to try one last time and ended up finding the solution on this article:

http://tomkrueger.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/azure-deployment-issue-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2010-and-net-4-0/

The problem started because I actually added an Azure project to an existing ASP.NET MVC solution there were some unnecessary settings left over in the `web.csproj` file.

All I had to do was open `web.csproj` in notepad and remove ***all*** occurrences of the `<PlatformTarget>` element.

My MVC prjoject was x86 and of course Azure works on x64 only. Even though I had the platform target set up as `AnyCPU` somehow Azure couldn't quite get along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the latest Azure SDK? .NET 4 was not supported before the June 2010 version of the SDK.

[Windows Azure Software Development Kit (June 2010)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21910585-8693-4185-826e-e658535940aa&displaylang=en)

[Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 1.2 (June 2010)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2274a0a8-5d37-4eac-b50a-e197dc340f6f&displaylang=en)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but yeah, it was the first thing I did before even trying to create a `CloudService` :(
I have edited my question to reflect the release date of the Azure tools I'm using. Thanks again